# Token Balances for sepolia testnet not updating in metamask

Tags: metamask, usdc, sepolia

Token Balances for sepolia testnet not updating in metamask when sent from faucet (aave in this case). I can send test ether which works appropriately. I have added tke token contract address (see image). I have tried all suggested fixes including restart, turning off add block, turning off vpn etc..(ref below) Transactions are verified on sepolia etherscan. Connections to sepolia are verfied. I have tried three browsers: chrome, firefox and brave - same issues. please help.

[https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360028059272-What-to-do-when-your-balance-of-tokens-is-incorrect#:~:text=Make%20sure%20your%20internet%20connection,to%20an%20alternative%2C%20where%20possible](https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360028059272-What-to-do-when-your-balance-of-tokens-is-incorrect#:%7E:text=Make%20sure%20your%20internet%20connection,to%20an%20alternative%2C%20where%20possible).

https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360038139452-MetaMask-states-Balance-may-be-outdated-displays-in-orange-or-ETH-not-added-to-balance

[image: aave faucet verification of account with no balance for USDC]